# Wordpress index content like this site?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I would like to know if there is a wordpress plugin for an index of content and this website:

http://www.bgproonline.com/blog/category/bg-news/

Thanks !!

Comment: Is it the images you mean, the ones who show the title and excerpt when you hover over them? Or is it the lists in the bottom you mean?

Comment: the ones who show the title and excerpt when you hover over them, is what I mean, when you hover your mouse over the title and goes click takes you to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any plugins that can do this automatically, but it shouldn't be to difficulty to do yourself, if you don't mind editing your theme. I made an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/westman/yx9gH/2/)

In the post loop, you can print each post like this:

```
<div class="block">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
        <div class="excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
        <div class="link">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Link to full post</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then use CSS link this to position the content over the image, hide it and then show it when you hover over the box:

```
.block {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
    position: relative;
}

.block .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}

.block:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```